# Stack expansion in application

Tags: vb.net, enumeration

I have a not-too-complicated problem which I do not know how to solve in VB.NET 2010.

Currently I have a recursive routine for finding files/and or searching. With a recursive routine I never complete the call until the end and process growth is significant enough to radically slow down the process with the now large stack.

To make maters worse, I use precoding routines which will take wildcards. Which are these:

```
Public Declare Function FindFirstFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "FindFirstFileA" (ByVal lpFileName As String, ByRef lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Integer
Public Declare Function FindNextFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "FindNextFileA" (ByVal hFindFile As Integer, ByRef lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Integer
Public Declare Function GetFileAttributes Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetFileAttributesA" (ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
Public Declare Function FindClose Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFindFile As Integer) As Integer
Public Declare Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "user32" Alias "LockWindowUpdate" (ByVal hwndLock As Long) As Long
```

How do I 'cure' this? They don't lend themselves to a non-recursive environment.

Comment: For starters, those P/Invoke definitions are wrong. It looks like you got them from an old VB 6 project. VB 6 is not compatible with VB.NET; the definitions need to be written differently. Check out www.pinvoke.net for some help. Don't use the A-suffixed versions, either. Windows has been fully Unicode for some years now.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4.0 now contains the enumerate files functionality in a single method call ([Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) Method):

> Returns an enumerable collection of file names that match a search
>   pattern in a specified path, and optionally searches subdirectories.

```
List<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(startFolder, "*.txt", 
                                              SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

VB.NET version:

```
Dim files As List(Of String) = Directory.EnumerateFiles(startFolder, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()
```